# aggregation at different levels, I need to get sum by type level in sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

```
ID      TYPE        AMT         PERIOD
-------------------------------------------
1001     1          4500        2008-09-30
1001     2          2333        2008-09-30
1001     2         -2333        2008-09-30
1001     1          -200        2008-09-30
1001     2           300        2008-09-30
```

Desired output:

```
ID      TYPE        AMT      PERIOD
------------------------------------
1001     1          4300    2008-09-30
1001     2           300    2008-09-30
```

I need to get sum of the `AMT` but still needs to include other columns, please see the desired output as shown above.

I tried using grouping sets but can't get it right.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,TYPE,SUM(AMT) as Total_Amt,PERIOD
FROM table
GROUP BY ID,TYPE,PERIOD
```